# How to download a file as a file

Tags: angular, firebase-storage, html5-audio, angularfire

I'm trying to figure out how to download an audio file I've uploaded to firebase storage as a file.  But all the various ways I've tried downloading the file, it just appears as an audio tag on another browser tab.

I've gathered that the `Content-Disposition` header is probably what I need to be dealing with, but I can't seem to find anything in the documentation or online in general about how to invoke the save file dialog of the browser when downloading the file.

I've used libraries like `file-saver` and I've tried `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` both they both behave the same way, which further makes me think that something needs to change on the firebase side.

## Update

As requested, I'm sharing full code snippets of what I've tried.

### Attempt with anchor tag

```js
import { getBlob, ref, Storage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

async download(song: Song) {
    const fileName = song.url.split('/').reverse()[0];
    const storageRef = ref(this._storage, `songs/${fileName}`);
    const blob = await getBlob(storageRef);

    const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = blobURL;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
}
```

### Attenmpt with `file-saver`

```js
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { getBlob, ref, Storage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

async download(song: Song) {
    const fileName = song.url.split('/').reverse()[0];
    const storageRef = ref(this._storage, `songs/${fileName}`);
    const blob = await getBlob(storageRef);

    saveAs(blob, fileName);
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a anchor tag with the `download` attribute set and the `href` attribute set and programmatically clicking the element.  This still just opens a new tab and shows the audio player.  So I tried a third-party library I've used in the past (`file-saver`) to see if they were able to solve this for me.  However, this still has the same behavior as opening the file in a new window.

As I've alluded to above, my own research into this issue seems to be tied with the content disposition header.  I'm not using the Angular `HttpClient`, as is obvious.  So I was hoping if anyone knew how to acquire the file from **Firebase Storage** such that I can coerce the browser into giving me the file as a file and not as a player piece of media in a separate tab.

Comment: In the past, I have simply included the Content-Type header in the response, with the appropriate type to cause a download.  You would then try to sent the Content-Type to audio file, to force a download.  With HTML 5, there seems to be an easy download attribute.  https://svarden.se/post/right-click-and-save-as

Comment: @StevenScott Thanks for the feedback.  I thought I showed enough code to be obvious what I've tried, but I'll update the question with full code snippets.

Comment: @StevenScott, I've updated my question.  Hopefully it is more obvious now where I am hung up.  The download attribute doesn't seem to always do what you are claiming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I genuinely don't know what happened between yesterday and today, but now `saveAs` from `file-saver` is doing what I want.  I apologize this doesn't provide more insight, but if I venture to guess, I was making a silly mistake somewhere.  I can't think of what's different from yesterday and today (I wasn't a good boy and didn't commit often).  But the following is working for me:

```js
  async download(song: Song) {
    const storageRef = ref(this._storage, `songs/${song.fileName}`);
    const blob = await getBlob(storageRef);
    saveAs(blob, song.fileName);
  }
```

I'm no longer grabbing the file name from the url, and instead I'm saving the url and fileName on the doc, but that's the only difference I can find from what I was trying previously.